# Wire chained lighting point with block terminal

Tags: lighting

There are two ceiling lighting points in the same room **connected in a chain**, i.e. a single switch controls both of them. As a result, one of these ceiling lighting points has **2 live, 2 neutral** and 1 ground wires:

[image]

The ceiling light I want to install has a block terminal which can connect with only 2 wires, 1 live and 1 neutral:

[image]

1. Can I use this block terminal and squeeze each pair of live/neutral wires inside each slot?
2. Or am I supposed to **replace** the terminal block with another one that allows 2 wires for live and 2 wires for neutral so that all 4 wires from both ceiling lighting points are connected? For example something like this one:

[image]
(diagram: https://www.switchelectronics.co.uk/pub/media/pdf/238L02.pdf)?

Answer (score 2):

There is no "magic trick" that makes ANY connector approved for 2 wires.  Some connectors are approved for multiple wires, on a case-by-case basis.

The labeling and instructions with the connector (or with the fixture if supplied with connector) should tell you.  Note that stuff sold mail order either direct from China, or via drop-shippers such as Amazon Fulfillment (including 3rd party sales from Amazon Marketplace) are often complete junk, lacking safe design nor any  genuine certifications. They won't have competent instructions either.  Such things are not legal for use in any western jurisdiction I am aware of. (e.g. NEC 110.2).  Send them back and get your money back.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To clarify, using the block terminal that only has 2 inputs (1 for each live and neutral) and squeezing in each input both wire pairs should not be done and I should instead find an appropriate terminal block that has 2 inputs for each live/neutral, correct?

If the above is correct, can you help me with how to search for such a block terminal; is it called "2 way double block terminal"?

Comment: @Yannis I would check your local electrical supply houses or home stores, as they will definitely have approved methods of splicing. They sell a whole ton of electrical gear to pretty much everyone wiring every house and business. So they know what's doing. Buying electrical mail-order is always risky due to all the junk on it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the OEM spec you published, you might be able to "squeeze" #14AWG double wires.

[image: squeeze]

Comment: Not sure which of the 2 options you suggest I follow. I edited my question to make it clear(er). 

Option 1 is squeezing the wire pairs (2 live in the live input and 2 neutral in the neutral input) into the block terminal that has only 2 slots (1 for neutral 1 for live). Whereas, the OEM spec is for a new terminal block is option 2.

Are you suggesting I go for option 1 in this case?

Comment: I posted my answer before you edited your post. Yes option 1 would also work like the option 2

Comment: It's only approved for 2 wires if it says 2 wires. I see the word "conductor" singular.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica A-hole**S**, B-hole**S**

Comment: That just means there are more than one hole for each `A`, `B` and `C`, not more than one conductor.